# How do I reference the databound control from an ObjectDataSource event?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, objectdatasource

Take for example a `DetailsView` control with an `ObjectDataSource` as its datasource.

Normally in the `DetailsView.ItemUpdated` event I would grab a reference to the details view by casting the `sender`:

```
DetailsView dv = (DetailsView)sender;
```

In certain situations it becomes necessary to handle the event inside the `ObjectDataSource.ItemUpdated` event. In this case `sender` is now of type `ObjectDataSource`. What I want to be able to do is write clean code that isnt hardcoded like

```
Label label1 = DetailsView1.FindControl("Label1");
```

I looked over the documentation and also did some searches but couldnt find how I would write some code like the following:

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
   ObjectDataSource ods = (ObjectDataSource)sender;
   DetailsView dv = (DetailsView)ods.SOMETHING_HERE;
}
```

Does anyone know what I should be putting in the `SOMETHING_HERE` in the snippet above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happen because the "OnInserted" event is suppose to be an event examine the values of a return value or output parameters, or to determine whether an exception was thrown after an Insert operation has completed. The return value, output parameters, and exception handling properties are available from the ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs object that is associated with the event.

What you can do here is just call `ObjectDataSource.select()` that returns the view in this case but I don't think it's a good choice.
You should review you business logic and try to manage it somewhere it makes more sense

Anyway your code should look like the below:

```
ObjectDataSource ods = YourDataSource.select(); 
DetailsView dv = (DetailsView)ods;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason that I am doing this is because I have a custom written `UserControl` which has a `TreeView` with checkboxes. It allows the user to select course/categories the item should be displayed in. I need to get a reference to this control so that I can update a different database table after the main item has been updated. I have easily solved the problem by just hardcoding the DetailsView name into it but I thought there may be some property kind of like .Parent or .NamingContainer that I could cast to so the code isn't so brittle.

Comment: It's hard to answer without look at your code. Anyway as long there is a reference to an object you can access its properties : from the usercontrol you can access the controls it contains and from the webcontrol you can access the parent (page or user control).

Answer (score 0):

Considering the example you provided, I don't think there is anything you can replace for Something_Here. It is the ODS linked to DV and not the other way. Also one DataSource can be linked to several DataBound Controls.
So as far as I know it is simply not possible.